# Add arguments to core search

Tags: 7, search

Is it possible to add arguments from $_GET to the core search?
For example:

search/term1/mystring

This search page should show results that have the "term1" term. Like views, but I've to add this function to core search :)

Answer (score 1):

certainly possible.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_preprocess/7

Check out that function.

Comment: But this function only preprocess keys for the search, I have to add filter to the query